# Args object not initialized AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

This is my code:

```
static void main(Args args)
{
    LedgerJournalId ledgerJournalId;
    HSinvoiceAcknowledgement hSinvoiceAcknowledgement = new HSinvoiceAcknowledgement();

    if (classidget(args.caller()) == classnum(syssetupformrun))
    {
        if (formhasmethod(args.caller(), identifierstr(HSjournalnum)))
        {
            ledgerjournalid = args.caller().HSjournalnum();
        }
    }

    if(ledgerJournalId)
    {
        hSinvoiceAcknowledgement.parmJournalNum(ledgerJournalId);
    }
    if (hSinvoiceAcknowledgement.prompt())
    {
        hSinvoiceAcknowledgement.run();
    }
}
```

I have **Args args** parameters in my main method however it says that

> Args object not initialized

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an additional check to make sure that `args` is not null. Replace

```
if (classidget(args.caller()) == classnum(syssetupformrun))
```

with

```
if (args && 
    args.caller() &&
    classidget(args.caller()) == classnum(syssetupformrun))
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help sir Aliaksandr!